# Make a object variable a pointer to another variable

Tags: ios, swift

This is far out of reach of my programming understanding, so any help understanding this concept would be very appreciated.

What I have is a layer class, FloaterContainerLayer.

```
class FloaterContainerLayer:CALayer {
    var gravity:CGFloat = 5.0
    var maxFloaters = 9
    var image:String?
    var velocity:CGFloat = 50.0
}
```

I have three instances of this class at all times. One of them is dotLayer.

```
lazy var dotLayer : FloaterContainerLayer = {
        let scrollLayer = FloaterContainerLayer()
        scrollLayer.bounds = self.view.layer.bounds
        scrollLayer.position = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.size.width/2, y: self.view.bounds.size.height/2)
        scrollLayer.image = "dot"
        scrollLayer.gravity = dotLayerGravity

        return scrollLayer
    }()
```

Somewhere else, I have a gravity variable for the dot layer.

```
var dotLayerGravity: CGFloat {
    get {
        if let stored = userDefaults.objectForKey("dotLayerGravity") {
            return CGFloat(stored as! NSNumber)
        }
        else {
            return 10.0
        }
    }
    set(value) {
        userDefaults.setValue(value, forKey: "dotLayerGravity")
    }
}
```

Now, this value can change at any time. I use `dotLayer.gravity` in a view rendering method I call 60 times per second.

What I would like to accomplish is that:

when I set
`dotLayer.gravity = dotLayerGravity`

and call 
`dotLayer.gravity`,

I want it to return `dotLayerGravity`.

Just setting the gravity variable in the class to the `dotLayerGravity` is not an option, as the class is used for three instances.

I tried this, but it doesn't work.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using CGFloat / Float /Double / Int ,... as pointers is not possible in Swift because they are value types. One possible solution is to create a simple wrapper class that would act as the pointer.

```
class CGFloatPointer : FloatLiteralConvertible {

    var value : CGFloat = 0

    required convenience init(floatLiteral value: Float) {
        self.init()
        self.value = CGFloat(value)
    }
}
```

You can extend this class with things like `FloatLiteralConvertible` to make it easier to use.

```
var gravity:CGFloatPointer = 5.0
```

This is much easier to maintain than `UnsafePointer`.

---

One tiny little detail. It sounds from your explanation that you are going to be loading/saving from/to UserDefaults a lot. This is bad, because it is slow.

For your piece of code I would recommend something that is half way between a global variable and a singleton and throws in some extra magic to regulate read/write operations.

```
class DotLayerGravity {
    private static var inMemory : CGFloat?
    static var value: CGFloat {
        get {
            if let inMemory = inMemory {
                return inMemory
            } else {
                let fetchedGravity = (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("dotLayerGravity") as? NSNumber) ?? 10
                inMemory = CGFloat(fetchedGravity)
                return inMemory!
            }
        }
        set(value) {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(value, forKey: "dotLayerGravity")
            // setting this to nil will make it fetch from permanenent storage.
            inMemory = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Because `value` is a `static` property it will be accessible everywhere in your App. This is not at all needed, but it does guarantee that there is only going to be one instance of this value.

`inMemory` is `private` and will hold the value from `NSUserDefaults` until a write operation has been done. It is `private` to give the class a cleaner interface.

When you get the value of `value` it will first check if it has a value in memory by unwrapping `inMemory`, if that is `nil`, it will fallback on `NSUserDefaults`, when that is also `nil`, it will fallback on a default value.

It will store the fetched or default value in `inMemory` and return the final result.
This ensures minimal reads from `NSUserDefaults`.

This is not thread safe, but can be made to be.

---

Rereading your question, made it clear to me that each instance has it's own `gravity` stored in `NSUserDefaults`. In that case I would make `FloaterContainerLayer` fully responsible for `gravity` by setting and `identifier` `String` that will be used to load/save to `NSUserDefaults`.

```
class FloaterContainerLayer:CALayer {

    var maxFloaters = 9
    var image:String?
    var velocity:CGFloat = 50.0

    var identifier : String = "floaterContainerIdentifier"

    private var inMemoryGravity : CGFloat?
    var gravity: CGFloat {
        get {
            if let inMemory = inMemoryGravity {
                return inMemory
            } else {
                let fetchedGravity = (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(identifier) as? NSNumber) ?? 10
                inMemoryGravity = CGFloat(fetchedGravity)
                return inMemoryGravity!
            }
        }
        set(value) {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(value, forKey: identifier)
            // setting this to nil will make it fetch from permanenent storage.
            inMemoryGravity = nil
        }
    }
}

class SomeViewController : UIViewController {

    lazy var dotLayer : FloaterContainerLayer = {
        let scrollLayer = FloaterContainerLayer()
        scrollLayer.bounds = self.view.layer.bounds
        scrollLayer.position = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.size.width/2, y: self.view.bounds.size.height/2)
        scrollLayer.image = "dot"
        scrollLayer.identifier = "dotLayerGravity"

        return scrollLayer
    }()
}
```

Comment: Thats a lot of good input. I was aware and kind of afraid of the UserDefaults part, which I figured i'd deal with later if it was a problem. From what i've read, it maintains a pretty OK cache which deals with the problem, but I'll use your solution if I have to. 

Regarding CGFloats not being point-able, are you sure about this? I found other people using it on here.

Comment: @OscarApeland I did not say they are not point-able (not even sure what that is), They just aren't reference types, so they don't have pointer behaviour on their own.

Comment: Oh. I misunderstood you then, I apologize. Turns out you were right about the NSUserDefaults part too, 100% CPU usage from frame 0.

Comment: @OscarApeland Nice! I always love a good 100% CPU, to me it always feels like an achievement. "Broke the System" badge acquired!

Comment: True that! :P One more question; How do I set your DotLayerGravity.value as the gravity property of one of my classes?

Comment: @OscarApeland thought you might ask, is at the end of the answer

Comment: I saw that, but I can't hardcode it to one specific value, as I have three instances of the FloaterContainerLayer class. So I need to be able to set it like dotLayer.gravity = DotLayerGravity.value or something that makes it go to the computed property

Comment: @OscarApeland updated, because it wasn't correct/clear. The `gravity` value should be computed. This way it will always read from `DotLayerGravity` and all instances will always have the same value. I also added the `setter`.

Comment: I think I am unclear as well. This does not work with my need to have dotLayer:FloaterContainerLayer, lineLayer:FloaterContainerLayer with their own dotGravity and lineGravity property. So I need a way to set which class value the Layer instance fetches its gravity from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108097/discussion-between-r-menke-and-oscar-apeland).

Answer (score 1):

Setting a reference pointer is only supported for functions, not properties. This means you need a set method

```
var testVariable: CGFloat = 100.0

class Test {
    var testPtr: UnsafePointer<CGFloat>?

    func setTestPtr(ptr: UnsafePointer<CGFloat>) {
        self.testPtr = ptr
    }
}

let t = Test()
t.setTestPtr(&testVariable)

testVariable = 110

let x = t.testPtr?.memory // 110
```